# oData V4 - returning unsorted data causing duplicate records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, odata

I have an oData model and am having trouble with default ordering on paged collections.

When I retrieve people from my database using 'odata/people', without any ordering in the query itself, the first page of my data comes back unsorted. However when going to the second page using the next link in the order model the data becomes sorted, meaning that I get duplicate records back in place of others. I am looking for a method to make the first page of data come back with some form of sorting without using any sorting in the query itself.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is supported by the spec? Or whether it is an issue with the .NET library.

I'm using: Microsoft.AspNet.OData - 7.2.3

Thanks in advance.